# Programming language without ELSE keyword - is it more complicated?

Tags: programming-languages, program-flow

I'm working on a simple programming language for kids, based on [Karel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karel_%28programming_language%29). For controlling program flow, I currently provide these facilities (in pseudocode):

- defining parameterless procedures
- if [not] EXPRESSION STATEMENT
- while [not] EXPRESSION STATEMENT

I don't have any means to return from a procedure, and **I don't provide the `else` statement.**

Take the following code for an example:

```
if something
 statement1
if not something
 statement2
```

The execution of code flows to `if`, executing `statement1` if `something` is true; 
then testing if `something` is not true (*but the state of the program has changed!*), then executing `statement2`. *This can lead to both tests succeeding.*

**Does this limit the programmer?** So far I've been able to solve all of my example problems by just using `if` ... `if not` ..., or using `if not` first, then `if`.

So, my question is:
**Is adding the `else` statement necessary?** It would make the language a bit more complicated with having more keywords. Are all problems that would be solvable with `else` statement solvable also without it, albeit more complicated?

Or is omitting the `else` statement actually making the language more complicated and counter-intuitive?

Comment: Well, it certainly seems that it makes it more complicated; to write the above, you have to take the trouble of writing `something` twice (or set a variable equal to `something` earlier.)  If you had two conditions, you would have to write them both again in the not-`else` clause to get the same behavior, and so on.  At least your kids will get good at applying De Morgan's laws!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `something` is expensive to evaluate then your language with `else` might give a problem because the evaluation will be performed twice.

Another potential problem is that if statement1 can modify the value of `something` you may end up with *both* tests succeeding - something that could not happen if you used else.

Of course these problems can be mitigated by storing the result in a temporary local variable:

```
bool result = something
if result
    statement1
if not result
    statement2
```

So no you aren't limiting the programmer in what is possible - everything that can be done with `else` can be done without it by using the above approach. But it is a little more code to write each time and it introduces a few new potential problems for the unwary programmer that would be avoided if you allowed `else`.

Comment: there is no way to store results in temporary local variables - there are no variables in this language. I'm wondering about the both tests succeeding - that's why I asked if you can do everything in a language without `else`, that you could do in a language with `else`

Comment: @Axarydax: Without local variables it might be difficult to write code that toggles some state because if you write "if state = A then state := B; if state = B then state := A" then if the initial state is A you'll set it first to B then straight back to A again. I am assuming that you have some state you can both read and modify.

Answer (score 3):

Semantically speaking you could avoid having the `else` construct, but from practical point of view I don't see any necessity of doing that.

The concept of *do something if something is true, otherwise something else* is not so strange and confusing, it sounds actually quite straightforward that having to evaluate and negate an expression again just to check its negation.. it's a free (in sense of "with no added complexity") optional synctactic sugar that is automatic when developing a language.

I saw many other features really more useless compared to the `else` statement.. then you are not considering the fact that evaluating a condition twice maybe harmful for **side-effects** or for **complexity** (wasted cpu?) or for the fact itself that you already have calculated it and you have to do it again for a **lack of the language** not because it's senseful.

Answer (score 1):

If `something` has side-effects than your approach will cause them to happen twice, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO It's bad idea to teach children to duplicate code.

Comment: is repeating a single one-word condition considered a duplicate code?